# Refining my code for data frame extraction from excel

Tags: r, dplyr

Looking for advice on refining my code and also trimming to a date range.

The spreadsheet itself is pulled from another system and so the structure of the excel cannot be changed. When you pull the data it basically starts at E2, with the first date column in F2, and the first item in E3. The data will continue to populate to the right for as long as it goes on for. I have replicated the structure below.

[image: Example of the structure of the excel]

AndI want it to look like:

[image]

I have come up with the below, which works, but I was looking for advice on refining it down to fewer individual step by steps.

In the below code:

1. = extracting data
2. = pulling the dates out
3. = formatting from
   excel number to an actual date
4. = grabbing the item names
5. = transposing data and skipping some parts
6. = adding in dates to the row names

```
#1
df <- data.frame(read_excel("C:/example.xlsx", 
                             sheet = "Sheet1"))
#2
dfdate <- gtb[1, -c(1,2,3,4,5)]
#3
dfdate <- format(as.Date(as.numeric(dfdate),
                        origin = "1899-12-30"), "%d/%m/%Y")
#4
rownames(gtb) <- gtb[,1]
#5
gtb <- as.data.frame(t(gtb[, -c(1,2,3,4,5)]))
#6
rownames(gtb) <- dfdate
```

After the row names have been added the structure is such that I am happy to start creating the visuals where needed.

thanks for your advice
David

Comment: Just note that transposing, `t` is a matrix operation. So your data.frame's column types will be coerced to character.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your approach. Its verbose, its clear, there is little doubt of what you are doing and what you want to achieve. A much more dense `all-in-one` dplyr approach isn't better just because it can connect all those code lines with a `%>%`

Comment: .. though I have learned to like `rownames_to_column` from tibble (and the reverse operation). It's one of those small things that is not talked about much, but is surprisingly useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one suggestion, I don't really have easy access to your data, but I am including code to remove those columns as you do, based on their names, which can be nicer than removing by index.

```r
df <- read.table( text=
"Item_Code 01/01/2018 01/02/2018 01/03/2018 01/04/2018
Item 99 51 60 69
Item2 42 47 88 2
Item3 36 81 42 48
",header=TRUE, check.names=FALSE) %>%
 rename( `Item Code` = Item_Code )

library(tibble)
library(lubridate)

x <- df %>% select( -matches("Code \\d|Internal Code") ) %>%
    column_to_rownames("Item Code") %>%
    t %>% as.data.frame %>%
    rownames_to_column("Item Code") %>%
    mutate( `Item Code` = dmy(`Item Code`) )

x
```

Output:

```
> x
   Item Code Item Item2 Item3
1 2018-01-01   99    42    36
2 2018-02-01   51    47    81
3 2018-03-01   60    88    42
4 2018-04-01   69     2    48
```

I went a bit forth and back with this solution, but it *can* be nice to also showcase how to remove columns by a regex on their column names, since you are removing several similarly named columns.

The `t` trick, that you also use, works becuase there is really only one more column there that would cause problems with this, as others have commented, and this can be temporarily stowed away as rownames. If that weren't the case, you're looking at a more complex solution involving pivot_wider and pivot_longer or splitting the data.frame and transposing only one of the halves.

Comment: Thanks very much I got the above to work, but I also appreciate the comment about dplyr  approach not necessarily being better. One question - on colnames(x)[-1] <- v1, there is no v1 mentioned previously.

Comment: thanks! You were not meant to see that, it was part of an eralier version of my answer, before storing column 1 as rownames, I saved it for later in v1 and added it back in, but after my edit I forgot to take it out (it is long gone now)